# How to implement common properties of the parent interface?

Tags: kotlin, oop, inheritance, interface

I want to implement common functionality in the parent interface at a single central location. I have:

- Common Interface: `Parent`
- Multiple Child Interfaces: `AChild, BChild...`

Whenever I try to implement any of these child interfaces, I find myself having to implement properties of the parent interface (`Parent`) each time, with the implementation being identical across the codebase.

How can I obtain implementations for the child interfaces (`AChild, BChild...`) without explicitly implementing the parent interface (`Parent`), under the assumption that the parent interface implementation will be done only once in a central location?

```
    interface Parent {
        val x: Int
    }
    
    interface AChild : Parent {
        val y: Int
    }
    
    interface BChild : Parent {
        val z: Int
    }
    
    class ASample(value: Int) {
        val aVariable: AChild = object : AChild {
            override val y = value + 20
            override val x = value
        }
    }
    
    class BSample(value: Int) {
        val bVariable: BChild = object : BChild {
            override val z = value + 10
            override val x = value
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're not already extending another class, you can create a common abstract class that provides the default implementation of `Parent`, and extend the abstract class. If you can't do this, use a delegate as suggested by VladDz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order that the parent interface implementation is executed only once in a central location, you can create a delegate as follows:

```
class ParentDelegate(value: Int) : Parent {
    override val x: Int = value
}
```

And than use it in your implementations for the child interfaces:

```
class ASample(value: Int) {
    val aVariable: AChild = object : AChild, Parent by ParentDelegate(value) {
        override val y: Int = value + 20
    }
}

class BSample(value: Int) {
    val bVariable: BChild = object : BChild, Parent by ParentDelegate(value) {
        override val z = value + 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much; this is precisely what I was looking for. It reduces the amount of code and maintains consistency.